# wysiwyg html editor build in html/javascript for position absolute elements

Tags: javascript, html, editor, wysiwyg

I'm currently on the stage of research for my new project. I'm looking for a wysiwyg html editor that builds the html elements with position absolute. The reason why I want this is because I want to give users more freedom when they design their pages. Something similar with designing a html page in photoshop.
I'm not looking for anything fancy. The users can only add rectangles(width, height, x,y , color) , text, image and probably some form elements(textarea, button, combo-box etc.)

So.. is there anything already done, that I could use , or I need to build it myself which could take some time and is not a priority for my project.

I know that are a lot of wysiwyg html editors but I couldn't find one that suits my needs: freedom in design.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer (Frontpage?), but an opinion: _don't_ build websites with lots of WYSIWYG absolute positioning - the web is not a print magazine or even a PDF document, and over-reliance on absolute positioning almost always ends up looking bad (for at least some users, if not all). You'll almost certainly blow any chances of meeting accessibility standards, in fact I'd expect an absolutely positioned website created with drag'n'drop to be almost useless to anybody trying to browse via a screen-reader.

Comment: Not only because of accessibility standards, but just because of reality. As soon as someone visits the site with an unexpected window size, zoom or just anything that hasn't been tested such designs are doomed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Most of the editors have this option to switch from static to absolute positioning.
There should be property to set for this purpose.