# WYSIWYG HTML editor with absolute positioned elements only

Tags: html, editor, positioning, wysiwyg, absolute

I have read a lot of criticism on using absolute positioning in HTML. Nevertheless, I am looking to have one simple Open Software tool which will enable me to have a quick HTML page PROTOTYPED with all elements having **ABSOLUTE positioning** through a drag and drop WYSIWYG mechanism. Typically even a SVG editor would have done and there are plenty of good ones but they do not have HTML form components to be dragged and dropped to give  a more realistic HTML proto look-and-feel to a page having Forms. If the prototype is acceptable in presentation, then all the other HTML, CSS, Jquery and other coding continues from there with the absolute positioning in place. The styles generated may be inline or separate, does not matter.

So, you will ask me why not use a real HTML editor in the first place? Well, the problem is that the steps after the prototype is accepted requires absolute positioning of elements only and all the HTML editors I reviewed do not have absolute positioned elements. I do not wish to clutter this question with what and why that is a requirement.
The prototype pages will be developed by not-so-expert HTML coders. Just some basic HTML elements but certainly all Form elements are all that I need.

To summarize:

1. What is the best FREE HTML WYSIWYG editor that is available on Windows and Linux which can give a drag and drop interface where the underlying HTML code generated has **absolute positioned** elements.
2. While on this topic, though this is more of a post-mortem question: What are the biggest downsides, if any, to absolute positioning of elements in HTML?

The question asked earlier by someone: [wysiwyg html editor build in html/javascript for position absolute elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071770) does not help either.

Comment: Did you found some tool? I want something similar too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot to ask for from an open source editor.  I can only empathize with your plight, as I too am one to expect a lot from my tools. The way I code the web is by hand (IDE / Text Editor... usually geany, Anjuta, or wxDev-C++) or I use a templte if the project needs to be done quickly. Obviously custom layouts and themes are sacrificed for that. The number one reason I code from scratch, no code generators meet my standards.

About absolute positioning in CSS, small screens often struggle to resolve issues like how to display an element that's absolutely 500px right of the left side of the screen when the screen only has a width of 350px... Mobile browsers do funny things as is through in absolute positioning and things are bound to get difficult.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help, happy coding, hope you find a suitable tool.